# WF 4 - How to react to events?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

There are some resources on the topic of State machines in WF4 ([WF4 State Machine Guidance](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/9/599CF8A9-5FE2-426A-A536-A83F84D38BF9/WF4%20State%20Machine%20Guidance.doc), [State machine activity pack CTP1](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/43586)), but I can't figure out how to react to events?

What I would like to do is something like:

```
 myWorkflow.SendEvent(Events.Stored);
```

And in transition branch to catch that *somehow* in trigger.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WF4 you send events by first creating bookmarks in your custom activities and then resuming these bookmarks. The standard event driven activities like Receive and Delay also work this way.